# which database to use

Tags: android

I am developing an App in which I need to authenticate password, store user personal information and setting details / preferences. All these are user-mobile specific or rather App specific and are unique for each user,the password and settings info should not be lost once phone is switched off or user exits the App, which data storage rocedure is recommended for such App?

Comment: You mean in one app you have multiple user registering on a single handset?

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked into SQLite?  There is a lot of support for sqlite with Andoid.
I would never use text files to store user data.  Especially considering the portability of SQLite.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Comment: Is frequent SQL DB access feasible for power usage considering the fact that, App is already constantly talking to Base station  to determine device speed.

Comment: From my experiance this is not a problem. Apple uses SQLite in iPhone, iTouch and iTunes, as well as Adobe and Symbian.  Are you making  1000s of hits to the DB on the phone?

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is the best solution. It's quick and easy to use. In my apps I've been able to perform 100s of SQL operations per second so I know performance won't be an issue for an app that just performs a query here and there.

The following SDK Link has a great explanation which will further answer your questions: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is certainly your best bet. However, if you are storing passwords, be sure to only store them as a salted hash, since apps with root permissions (if your app is ever installed on a rooted phone) read and even alter the sqlite databases of other apps. It's probably best never to store passwords in plaintext anywhere they can be read!